# How do I extract tabular data that's embedded within a non-tabular text-file?

Tags: regex, perl, text-processing, text-parsing

Have few thousand reports that have consistently formatted tabular data embedded within them that I need to extract.

Have a few ideas, but thought I'd post to see if there's a better way to do this than what I'm thinking; which is to extract the tabular data, create a new file for it, then parse that data as a tabular file.

Here's a sample input and output, where the output read and written row by row to a database.

**INPUT_FILE**

```
MiscText MiscText MiscText
MiscText MiscText MiscText
MiscText MiscText MiscText
SubHeader
PASS    1283019238  alksdjalskdjl
FAIL    102310928301    kajdlkajsldkaj
PASS    102930192830    aoisdajsdoiaj
PASS    192830192301    jiasdojoasi
MiscText MiscText MiscText
MiscText MiscText MiscText
MiscText MiscText MiscText
```

**OUTPUT** (read/write row-by-row from text-file to DB)

```
ROW-01{column01,column02,column03}
...
ROW-nth{column01,column02,column03}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recognizing when to start processing tabular data is easy. You've got the marker line. The difficulty is recognizing when to stop processing data. You can apply the heuristics of stopping to process data when the `split` doesn't yield the expected result.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $tab_data;
my $num_cols;
while ( <> ) {
    $tab_data = 1, next if $_ eq "SubHeader\n";
    next unless $tab_data;
    chomp;
    my @cols = split /\t/;
    $num_cols ||= scalar @cols;
    last if $num_cols and $num_cols != scalar @cols;
    print join( "\t", @cols ), "\n";
}
```

Save as `etd.pl` (etd = extract tabular data, what did you think?), and call it like this from the command line:

```
perl etd.pl < your-mixed-input.txt
```

Comment: @Michael Ludwig: Thanks, look great -- though it appears I'm missing something. I've posted the code in the body of my question with $tab_data getting the sample data. When I run the code in a Perl debugger I use all the time (Ptkdb) the perl crashes/hanges at the while statement. Any idea what's going on, or what I'm missing? Again, thanks!

Comment: @blunders, the script expects the data streaming in on `STDIN`, which is standard input. Open up a command prompt and give it a try. - Ah, and please revert your edit to your original post - it is totally misleading, and not as intended at all. Thanks.

Comment: +2 @Michael Ludwig: Reverted the body of the question. Follow your edits, though heading out of the office for a few hours, but expect to get back to this within 24-hours. Again, thank you!

Comment: When will `$tab_data` not be 1?

Comment: @TLP - `$tab_data` will only be set to one when `$_ eq "SubHeader\n"`. Do `perl -MO=Deparse,-p etd.pl` or `perl -d` to verify.

Comment: `$tab_data` will remain 1 for the rest of the file after "SubHeader", though, which makes it useful only for the first pass. Isn't it a bit obfuscating to write it this way? Why not `if ($_ eq "SubHeader\n") { $tab_data = 1; next; }`?

Comment: @TLP - You're right, it's only for one pass. And I agree the solution is not perfect. However, given the spec, it's certainly not inappropriate. And yes, it's a little bit obfuscating.

Comment: +4 total and selected as answer @Lumi: Played around with your code, and while I agree with @TLP that it's not the most clear code (which may have more to do with Perl) - it works as required, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you know how to extract data, why create a new file instead of processing it immediately?

Comment: +1 @zvrba: That's what I'd like to do, though I'd still have to figure out how to do it; all the code I've used so far OPEN<filehandle> a file, uses a WHILE<filehandle>, then CLOSE<filehandle> the file; no idea how to twist that into parse text by linefeeds. As for extracting the data, I just know it's possible; updated the sample data to give you a better idea of what I mean; that being the sub-header is always the same, and the tabular data goes on until there is not a (PASS or FAIL) on the next line.

Answer (score 0):

In case this is a fixed width data, I would strongly suggest using `unpack` or plain old `substr`.